# Populating list box values with sql + html

Tags: html, sql

I am trying to make a drop down list that is populated by a sql database.  The sql call is populating the list, but when I try to get the value= part it just doesn't work right.

I want its value= to be the location_id  then what is displayed to the user to be the location_description.  However, when I do the code below, the value= is the location_description and what is displayed to the user is the location_id.  If i reverse the order, it doesn't help.

```
<select name="building" id="building">
            ~[tlist_sql;SELECT DISTINCT location_description, location_id FROM u_locations ORDER BY location_description]
                <option value="~(location_id)" >~(location_description)</option>
            [/tlist_sql]
            </select>
```

The result is:

```
 <select name="building" id="building">

                <option value="ADAM">1</option>

                <option value="ADMIN">0</option>

                <option value="BRON">12</option>

                <option value="CLA">3</option>

                <option value="CLATT">15</option>

                <option value="COQ">18</option>

                <option value="DAR">19</option>


            </select>
```

But I need it to be the reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this work ?

```
<select name="building" id="building">
        ~[tlist_sql;SELECT DISTINCT location_id,location_description FROM u_locations ORDER BY location_description]
            <option value="~(location_id)" >~(location_description)</option>
        [/tlist_sql]
        </select>
```

I just reversed the fields in the SELECT list

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me. I would suspect there to either be:

- The table actually contains the description in the location_id column
- caching problems in either the web server or the browser.

Try restarting your web server and clearing your web cache in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

As per [w3schools documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) `ORDER BY` keyword sorts the records in `ascending` order by default

Simply to reverse, add `ORDER BY location_description DESC`